# Static methods identification in Method Table (WinDBG)

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg

Is there a way to know if method is static be exploring the Method Table using WinDBG? 
I know that there is static fields and methods in MD, but I can't understand how to identify that some method is a static or not.

I know that I can check function parameters and see if "this" is passed to a function (cause static functions doesn't accept this as a parameter)- but, is there a more straightforward way?

Scenario:

> 1. Listing threads - "!threads".
> 2. Setting current thread - "~3s".
> 3. Listing thread stack - "!CLRStack"
> 4. Picking one function by MD and calling "!ip2md 00007ffae9870da4"

What I get:

```
0:000> !IP2MD 0290059f 
MethodDesc:   02775b14
Method Name:  WindBG_POC.Program+TetsStatics.StaticFunction()
Class:        02771874
MethodTable:  02775b28
mdToken:      06000003
Module:       02773fdc
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     02900558
Transparency: Critical
Source file:  ....\Program.cs @ 29
```

Comment: `!SOS.dumpclass 2771874`

Comment: @SteveJohnson: that doesn't list methods, unfortunately

Comment: Whoops...I was thinking fields. My mistake.